# Mariadb MySQL count distinct group by performance

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, mariadb, explain

Mariadb verion

```
select version();
version()                                |
-----------------------------------------+
10.4.24-MariaDB-1:10.4.24+maria~focal-log|
```

I have a table like the following sql. col a mean version. col b,c,d,e seems like database,schema,table,field.

```
CREATE TABLE tt (a int, b varchar(32), c varchar(64), d varchar(64), e varchar(64), f int) 
CREATE INDEX tt_a_IDX USING BTREE ON tt (a,b,c,d,e);
```

table count is 510114

The first question is about the difference between 2 querys when getting col e count in the specific version.

```
sql1. select count(DISTINCT c,d,e),b from tt where a = 1 group by b;
sql2. select sum(count), b from (
                select b,COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count from tt 
                where a = 1
                GROUP BY  b,c,d) tt group by b;

id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref  |rows  |Extra                   |
--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+------+------------------------+
 1|SIMPLE     |tt   |ref |tt_a_IDX     |tt_a_IDX|5      |const|253768|Using where; Using index|

id|select_type|table     |type|possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref  |rows  |Extra                          |
--+-----------+----------+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+------+-------------------------------+
 1|PRIMARY    |<derived2>|ALL |             |        |       |     |253768|Using temporary; Using filesort|
 2|DERIVED    |tt        |ref |tt_a_IDX     |tt_a_IDX|5      |const|253768|Using where; Using index       |
```

1 cost 4s on average, 2 cost only hundreds of ms;

q1. Why second sql is faster? So does this mean count(distinct mutil cols...) can replace by "group by mutil cols and sum" for the permance?

The second question is when i add column **a** in the group by condition, the plan show a range type select. but in fact, its cost more time.

```
sql3. select sum(count), b from (
                select b,COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count from tt 
                where a = 1
                GROUP BY  a,b,c,d) temp group by b;

id|select_type|table     |type |possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref|rows  |Extra                                           |
--+-----------+----------+-----+-------------+--------+-------+---+------+------------------------------------------------+
 1|PRIMARY    |<derived2>|ALL  |             |        |       |   |253768|Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
 2|DERIVED    |tt        |range|tt_a_IDX     |tt_a_IDX|689    |   |253768|Using where; Using index for group-by (scanning)|
```

cost about 3s on average;

q2. What happens?

since the key_len show in the plan, i drop the index and make a new index only in col a

```
explain select count(DISTINCT c,d,e),b from tt where a = 1 group by b  ;
explain select sum(count), b from (
                select b,COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count from tt 
                where a = 1
                GROUP BY  b,c,d) temp group by b ;
id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref  |rows  |Extra                      |
--+-----------+-----+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+------+---------------------------+
 1|SIMPLE     |tt   |ref |tt_a_IDX     |tt_a_IDX|5      |const|253768|Using where; Using filesort|
id|select_type|table     |type|possible_keys|key     |key_len|ref  |rows  |Extra                          |
--+-----------+----------+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----+------+-------------------------------+
 1|PRIMARY    |<derived2>|ALL |             |        |       |     |253768|Using temporary; Using filesort|
 2|DERIVED    |tt        |ref |tt_a_IDX     |tt_a_IDX|5      |const|253768|Using where; Using filesort    |
```

in the explain,there is little difference, but two query cost more, about  5s, 4s on average

q3. Does this mean index (a,b,c,d,e) make effect in fact, not like the plan show(key_len)?

analyze result:

```
ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON select count(DISTINCT c,d,e),b 
from tt where a = 1 group by b; 

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 3222.2,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "tt",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": ["tt_a_IDX"],
      "key": "tt_a_IDX",
      "key_length": "5",
      "used_key_parts": ["a"],
      "ref": ["const"],
      "r_loops": 1,
      "rows": 253768,
      "r_rows": 510114,
      "r_total_time_ms": 395.73,
      "filtered": 100,
      "r_filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "tt.a <=> 1",
      "using_index": true
    }
  }
}

ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON select sum(count), b
from
    (
    select b, COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count
    from tt where a = 1 GROUP BY b, c, d
    ) temp
group by b;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 662.82,
    "filesort": {
      "sort_key": "tt.b",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "r_total_time_ms": 0.0086,
      "r_limit": 200,
      "r_used_priority_queue": false,
      "r_output_rows": 16,
      "r_buffer_size": "2Kb",
      "temporary_table": {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "<derived2>",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "r_loops": 1,
          "rows": 253768,
          "r_rows": 2652,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.1939,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "materialized": {
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "r_loops": 1,
              "r_total_time_ms": 661.61,
              "table": {
                "table_name": "tt",
                "access_type": "ref",
                "possible_keys": ["tt_a_IDX"],
                "key": "tt_a_IDX",
                "key_length": "5",
                "used_key_parts": ["a"],
                "ref": ["const"],
                "r_loops": 1,
                "rows": 253768,
                "r_rows": 510114,
                "r_total_time_ms": 245.18,
                "filtered": 100,
                "r_filtered": 100,
                "attached_condition": "tt.a <=> 1",
                "using_index": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON select sum(count), b
from
    (
    select b, COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count
    from tt where a = 1 GROUP BY a,b, c, d
    ) temp
group by b;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 3401.7,
    "filesort": {
      "sort_key": "tt.b",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "r_total_time_ms": 0.0093,
      "r_limit": 200,
      "r_used_priority_queue": false,
      "r_output_rows": 16,
      "r_buffer_size": "2Kb",
      "temporary_table": {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "<derived2>",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "r_loops": 1,
          "rows": 253768,
          "r_rows": 2652,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.406,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "materialized": {
            "query_block": {
              "select_id": 2,
              "r_loops": 1,
              "r_total_time_ms": 3400.5,
              "table": {
                "table_name": "tt",
                "access_type": "range",
                "possible_keys": ["tt_a_IDX"],
                "key": "tt_a_IDX",
                "key_length": "689",
                "used_key_parts": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
                "r_loops": 1,
                "rows": 253768,
                "r_rows": 510071,
                "r_total_time_ms": 3091.2,
                "filtered": 100,
                "r_filtered": 100,
                "attached_condition": "tt.a = 1",
                "using_index_for_group_by": "scanning"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

update1 :
i try to import data from mariadb to mysql8. three sql show no obvious difference.

update2 : explain analyze result in mysql8

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(DISTINCT c,d,e),b 
from tt where a = 1 group by b; 
-> Group aggregate: count(distinct tt.c,tt.d,tt.e)  (cost=71893.42 rows=253768) (actual time=0.882..3453.691 rows=16 loops=1)
    -> Covering index lookup on tt using tt_a_IDX (a=1)  (cost=46516.62 rows=253768) (actual time=0.030..411.063 rows=510114 loops=1)

EXPLAIN ANALYZE select sum(count), b
from
    (
    select b, COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count
    from tt where a = 1 GROUP BY b, c, d
    ) temp
group by b;
-> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=1113.183..1113.185 rows=16 loops=1)
    -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=1113.182..1113.182 rows=16 loops=1)
        -> Table scan on temp  (cost=97270.23..100444.82 rows=253768) (actual time=1111.180..1111.563 rows=2652 loops=1)
            -> Materialize  (cost=97270.22..97270.22 rows=253768) (actual time=1111.177..1111.177 rows=2652 loops=1)
                -> Group aggregate: count(distinct tt.e)  (cost=71893.42 rows=253768) (actual time=0.153..1109.965 rows=2652 loops=1)
                    -> Covering index lookup on tt using tt_a_IDX (a=1)  (cost=46516.62 rows=253768) (actual time=0.043..398.208 rows=510114 loops=1)

EXPLAIN ANALYZE select sum(count), b
from
    (
    select b, COUNT(DISTINCT e) as count
    from tt where a = 1 GROUP BY a,b, c, d
    ) temp
group by b;
-> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=4762.307..4762.309 rows=16 loops=1)
    -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=4762.306..4762.306 rows=16 loops=1)
        -> Table scan on temp  (cost=76130.41..79305.00 rows=253768) (actual time=4760.310..4760.708 rows=2652 loops=1)
            -> Materialize  (cost=76130.40..76130.40 rows=253768) (actual time=4760.308..4760.308 rows=2652 loops=1)
                -> Group aggregate: count(distinct tt.e)  (cost=50753.60 rows=253768) (actual time=0.388..4757.575 rows=2652 loops=1)
                    -> Filter: (tt.a = 1)  (cost=25376.80 rows=253768) (actual time=0.055..4593.786 rows=510071 loops=1)
                        -> Covering index skip scan for deduplication on tt using tt_a_IDX over (a = 1)  (cost=25376.80 rows=253768) (actual time=0.051..4535.554 rows=510071 loops=1)
```

update 3: data distribution

```
select count(distinct a) from tt;
count(distinct a)|
-----------------+
                1|
mark: there is only one value for col a, which is 1.

select count(distinct a,b) from tt;
count(distinct a,b)|
-------------------+
                 16|

select count(distinct a,b,c) from tt;
count(distinct a,b,c)|
---------------------+
                   28|

select count(distinct a,b,c,d) from tt;
count(distinct a,b,c,d)|
-----------------------+
                   2652|

select count(distinct a,b,c,d,e) from tt;
count(distinct a,b,c,d,e)|
-------------------------+
                   510071|

select count(distinct a,b,c,d,e,f) from tt;
count(distinct a,b,c,d,e,f)|
---------------------------+
                      49680|
```

Comment: Interesting case. Take a look at [ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) output for the query. In theory it could use the index very efficiently. How much fof the table corresponds to `a=1`? In theory you should write the simplest, and accurate query possible, and with the right table stats the database should work out the optimal plan. If it doesn't write a test case and bug report. Heavy optimizer improvements are in MariaDB-11.0+, Monty probably will jump on any bad query that happens in a later version than this and fix it.

Comment: Hi danblack. Sorry, this is my first time asking a question using stackoverflow, now I have put the analyze results into the question

Comment: "Average time" is less indicative than "second".  The _first_ run may need to read stuff from disk, plus other one-time actions.  This slower first-time clouds the average.

Comment: What percent of the table has a=1?  I'm wondering if the slower one failed to do the filtering that the faster one did.

Comment: I did a test with data with 100% a=1 -> `insert into tt select 1, mod(seq, 5), mod(seq, 11), mod(seq, 15), mod(seq, 22), seq from seq_1_to_1000000;` and got on the latest 10.4 a query time is 0.324 seconds.

Comment: Hi Rick. "Average time" is not a exact calculation. I just remove some bad test because sometimes the database run abnormally.  and col a of all data is 1.

Comment: Hi danblack. I have placed the distribution of data in the table in the update 3.

Comment: Hi danblack. lets try ``` insert into tt2 select 1, 2, 3, concat("testtable-------",mod(seq, 2600)), concat("testfield-------",mod(seq, 500000)), mod(seq, 36) from seq_1_to_500000;```;,which is closer to the current data distribution situation. and the data constructed through this SQL can show certain differences among the three queries, but it is not as large as my current data. and when the length of testtable and testfield become larger, the sql1 and sql3 query cost more time.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the query `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` in the q1 maintains a tree of the element encountered when walking the index and counting the result at the end. When walking such a list in order, the difference to the previous element walked only needs to be considered.

This could be implemented better and I wrote up the feature requests [MDEV-32870](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30660). An existing feature request [MDEV-10922](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10922) exists also that applies to a primary key (which could discard any internals and treat as `COUNT(*)`).

The other queries managed to generate smaller set at a time so managed to be quicker.